# Apache NiFi rethinkdb connection

Tags: apache-nifi, rethinkdb

I'm trying to use PutRethinkDB processor in NiFi.

Below are the properties configured. (This is a test setup so nifi and rethinkdb are on same machine and rethinkdb has no password setup yet).

[image]

When I run the flow, PutRethinkDB processor shows below error.
`Error while getting connection null: java.lang.NullPointerException`

[image]

I have verified that RethinkDB is running and bound to all IP addresses on port 28015.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly,  you should look at `nifi-app.log` for more informations. If it's not enough, according to the documentation, you should inspect `rethinkdb.error.message` attribut to take a look at RethinkDB side error.

1. pause your putSyslog processor
2. make flowfile to generate error
3. inspect flowfile attribut in queue

Comment: Thanks. I checked the log and could infer that it was a trivial error. I assumed that rethinkdb can be connected with default credentials (admin/blank). After setting password for rethinkdb and setting that password in PutRethinkDB's configuration, it started working. If the error would have been more explicit, much time would have been saved.